# Create a view from Select statement with multiple subqueries

Tags: mysql, view

```
SELECT z.`id`, z.`ukupno` ,s.uk, (ukupno-uk) as r from zbirni z
 join 
(SELECT k.`iddzid`,  (sum(kolicina*cjena)) as uk FROM   kasa k   join kasa_detalji d on d.idd=k.id group by  iddzid) as s 
on s.iddzid=z.id
 where (ukupno-uk)>0
```

but i have error
Script line: 1  View's SELECT contains a subquery in the FROM clause

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can rewrite your query with joins to avoid usage of subquery and Mysql view's limitation

```
SELECT 
z.`id`, 
z.`ukupno` ,
SUM(kolicina * cjena) uk, 
(ukupno - SUM(kolicina * cjena)) AS r 
FROM zbirni z
 JOIN kasa k  ON(z.id=k.`iddzid`)
 JOIN kasa_detalji d ON (d.idd=k.id)
GROUP BY z.`id`
HAVING r > 0
```

or create view for each subquery and use it in your view like

```
CREATE VIEW calc_sum
AS 
SELECT k.`iddzid`,  
SUM(kolicina*cjena) AS uk FROM   kasa k  
JOIN kasa_detalji d ON d.idd=k.id 
GROUP BY  iddzid
```

use `calc_sum` view in your query

```
CREATE VIEW your_view_name
SELECT 
z.`id`, 
z.`ukupno` ,
s.uk, 
(ukupno-uk) AS r 
FROM zbirni z
 JOIN  calc_sum AS s ON s.iddzid=z.id
WHERE (ukupno-uk)>0
```